# .net MAUI - Animate slow scroll of a list of items

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am currently working on a Display-Application for a small company, which will use an AndroidTV (but maybe a Windows PC) to show important information at the store window. As .NET Maui is the new approach for multi-platform apps, I am using the framework to build this app.

Currently I have a CollectionView showing current items for sale by getting them from a REST call. What I want to do now, is to animate a slow scroll of the CollectionView from start to end and back again, to get the attention of passing people. As .NET Maui is quite new I couldn't find anything on google, so that's why I am asking here, if it is possible to do so or if I need to change my approach with a non-scrollable View and transform the X value.

Thanks in advance, hopefully someone has an idea how to get this working.

Comment: Did you checkout the documentation of the CollectionView: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling?view=net-maui-7.0 already? You could have a timer or something in your ViewModel which controls which item should be scrolled to and then call `ScrollTo()` or `ScrollToPosition()` from within your View's code behind.

Comment: @ewerspej - that won't perform a *slow* scroll.

Comment: @RaphiiWarren,, to have control over speed, you'll need an Animation of X or Y (as you mention as an alternative approach).

Comment: @ewerspej Yes I tried that, and as Steve mentioned it does not perform a slow scroll.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for that comment, after you told me that this is the right approach, I started fiddling with it and came to a pretty easy way of working that out. Gonna post an answer to help others finding this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@ToolmakerSteve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199364/toolmakersteve) mentioned in the comments, the right approach is to use Translate for slow animation. I'm gonna show how I used it in my case to help others in the future.

Instead of using a CollectionView you can use a HorizontalStackLayout (or VerticalStackLayout) to show all items you want to scroll through:

```html
<HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="ItemList" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!-- Your DataTemplate -->
    </DataTemplate>
  </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

After that you can translate the X value and width (or Y value and height for VerticalStackLayout) so you generate a "scroll", with the code shown below. In my case I gave each element 3 seconds for an optimal speed, but that value can be set however you want it. Additionally I moved the list back to start for a loop, but if you don't need that you can leave it.

```c#
  private async Task MoveItemListToEnd()
  {
    double completeWidth = ItemListStackLayout.Children.Last().Frame.X + ItemListStackLayout.Children.Last().Frame.Width;
    double visibleWidth = ItemListStackLayout.Width;
    double moveWidth = completeWidth - visibleWidth;
    uint speed = (3000 * Convert.ToUInt32(ItemListStackLayout.Children.Count));
    await VehicleListStackLayout.TranslateTo(-moveWidth, 0, speed, Easing.Linear);
    await MoveItemListToStart();
  }

  private async Task MoveItemListToStart()
  {
    uint speed = (3000 * Convert.ToUInt32(ItemListStackLayout.Children.Count));
    await ItemListStackLayout.TranslateTo(0, 0, speed, Easing.Linear);
    await MoveVehicleListToEnd();
  }
```

I hope that my answer is gonna help people coming to this question in the future.